# QUERY: SELECT and show only A where F2 is true; order by I where F12 is true, limit 5 where F36 is true

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, gs-vlookup

I am trying to analyze shares and ETFs via the google sheets query function.
[image]

This function is running.

In my next step, I want to extend the main function by some features/filters.

[image]

Here are the features/filters I have tried with more and less success ...

Feature 1: Select from DATA only A --> when F2 is TRUE

```
=query(WATCHLIST!A1:BC;"Select " &E2& " where " &E2& " ="&(IF(F2=TRUE;E2;""))&"")
```

extended version

```
=query(WATCHLIST!A1:BC;"Select " &E2& ","&E4&",I where " &E2& " ="&(IF(F2=TRUE;E2;""))&" or where " &E4& " ="&(IF(F4=TRUE;E4;""))&"")
```

Feature2: Select from CLASS where C contains DIVIDEND

```
=query(WATCHLIST!A1:BC;"select A,C,I where C='"&(IF(B2=TRUE;A2;""))&"'")
```

This function is running.

Feature 3: order by I desc where F24 is TRUE

I am not sure how to solve it with a where clause. In my case, it is not running

Feature 4: limit 5 where F36 is TRUE

I am not sure how to solve it with a where clause. In my case, it is not running

Maybe someone has some ideas. This would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(WATCHLIST!A1:BC; 
 "select "&TEXTJOIN(","; 1; FILTER(E2:E21; F2:F21=TRUE))&" 
  where C matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|"; 1; FILTER(A2:A; B2:B=TRUE))&"'"&
  IF(COUNTIF(F24:F33; TRUE)>0; "order by "&TEXTJOIN(","; 1; FILTER(E24:E33; F24:F33=TRUE))&
  IF(F36=TRUE; " limit 5"; ); ); 1))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Dear player0, thank your for your support. The function is running great. Therefore I have a question regarding the "order by"-function. In your case the performance of the shares is sorted ascending in the list. It shows the last 5 shares ascending, if I use this part of the function. It would be great if I can help my function to be sorted DESCENDING. Many thanks in advance J.

Comment: Here is my running solution for a "descending" formula:       =ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(WATCHLIST!A1:BC; 
 "select "&TEXTJOIN(","; 1; FILTER(E2:E21; F2:F21=TRUE))&" 
  where C matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|"; 1; FILTER(A2:A; B2:B=TRUE))&"'"&
  IF(COUNTIF(F24:F33; TRUE)>0; "order by "&TEXTJOIN(","; 1; FILTER(E24:E33; F24:F33=TRUE))&
  IF(F36=TRUE; " desc limit 5"; ); ); 1))